# What is the default filetype association for .conf files?

Tags: windows-7, file-association, file-types

I accidentally changed the filetype association on **.conf** files when I was viewing one.  What is the default association for this type of file in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no initial default file type associated with .conf files. Personally, I usually set them to open with Notepad.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where my setting is so it won't execute.

Comment: What are you trying to execute? What file exactly, and what are you expecting to happen? They don't execute, they are just read in raw mode by programs that use them. Are you thinking about a .cmd file, which will execute?

Comment: I found my mistake, just misremembered how I had run it before (as a parameter to an executable).  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Conf files are not executable. They contain no code (at least for running themselves). They would only do something as a parameter for an actual executable program. But Notepad is a good choice for an association since they will then open for editing with a click.